# What is wrong with `std::set`?

Tags: c++, string, stl, set, remove-if

In [the other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396413/char-array-sorting-and-removing-duplicates) I was trying to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396413/char-array-sorting-and-removing-duplicates) problem. The problem was to remove duplicate characters from a `std::string`.

```
std::string s= "saaangeetha";
```

Since the order was not important, so I sorted `s` first, and then used `std::unique` and finally resized it to get [the desired result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396413/char-array-sorting-and-removing-duplicates/5396523#5396523):

```
aeghnst
```

That is correct!

---

Now I want to do the same, but at the same time I want the order of characters intact. Means, I want this output:

```
sangeth
```

So I wrote [this](http://ideone.com/mDo3N):

```
template<typename T>
struct is_repeated
{
    std::set<T>  unique;
    bool operator()(T c) { return !unique.insert(c).second; }
}; 
int main() {
    std::string s= "saaangeetha";
    s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), is_repeated<char>()), s.end()); 
    std::cout << s ;
}
```

Which gives this output:

```
saangeth
```

That is, `a` is repeated, though other repetitions gone. What is wrong with the code?

Anyway I [change my code](http://ideone.com/DtDaN) a bit: (see the comment)

```
template<typename T>
struct is_repeated
{
    std::set<T> & unique;  //made reference!
    is_repeated(std::set<T> &s) : unique(s) {} //added line!
    bool operator()(T c) { return !unique.insert(c).second; }
}; 
int main() {
    std::string s= "saaangeetha";
    std::set<char> set; //added line!
    s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(),s.end(),is_repeated<char>(set)),s.end()); 
    std::cout << s ;
}
```

Output:

```
sangeth
```

Problem gone!

So what is wrong with the first solution?

Also, if I don't make the member variable `unique` reference type, then [the problem doesn't go](http://ideone.com/YsiNd).

What is wrong with `std::set` or `is_repeated` functor? Where exactly is the problem?

**I also note that if the `is_repeated` functor is copied somewhere, then every member of it is also copied. I don't see the problem here!**

Comment: As an aside, sorting the data is O(N log N).  There is a much more efficient algorithm for doing this.  Make a linear pass of the string, counting the occurrences of each character.  Make a second pass of the string and only output if the count is 1.  This is O(N).

Comment: You do not need two passes. Simply make a bool array and check if bFound[c] == true if false you append it to the result string and set bFound[c]=true. This way you build up a filter and use it in one pass.

Comment: @Jeff: Or use an unordered_set instead of a set.

Comment: @Kenny: Unfortunately, that is not working. It still reorders :-s

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[In GCC (libstdc++)](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01044_source.html#l01131), `remove_if` is implemented essentially as

```
    template<typename It, typename Pred>
    It remove_if(It first, It last, Pred predicate) {
      first = std::find_if(first, last, predicate);
    //                                  ^^^^^^^^^
      if (first == last)
         return first;
      else {
         It result = first;
         ++ result;
         for (; first != last; ++ first) {
           if (!predicate(*first)) {
    //          ^^^^^^^^^
              *result = std::move(*first);
              ++ result;
           }
         }
      }
    }
```

Note that your predicate is passed *by-value* to `find_if`, so the struct, and therefore the set, modified inside `find_if` will not be propagated back to caller.

Since the first duplicate appears at:

```
  saaangeetha
//  ^
```

The initial `"sa"` will be kept after the `find_if` call. Meanwhile, the `predicate`'s set is empty (the insertions within `find_if` are local). Therefore the loop afterwards will keep the 3rd `a`.

```
   sa | angeth
// ^^   ^^^^^^
// ||   kept by the loop in remove_if
// ||
// kept by find_if
```

Comment: +1. This explains the behaviour. It all depends on the implementation of `std::remove_if`.

Comment: Alright. The bottomline of all these analysis, and learning is that : **functor must not have state**. Right?

Comment: Not necessarily.  For example, the for_each algorithm accepts a functor and then returns it after applying it everywhere, with the understanding that it should indeed be modified.  However, predicates and comparison functors should not have state, since they're supposed to represent mathematical comparisons, which should not mutate over time.

Answer (score 17):

Functors are supposed to be designed in a way where a copy of a functor is identical to the original functor.  That is, if you make a copy of one functor and then perform a sequence of operations, the result should be the same no matter which functor you use, or even if you interleave the two functors.  This gives the STL implementation the flexibility to copy functors and pass them around as it sees fit.

With your first functor, this claim does not hold because if I copy your functor and then call it, the changes you make to its stored set do not reflect in the original functor, so the copy and the original will perform differently.  Similarly, if you take your second functor and make it not store its set by reference, the two copies of the functor will not behave identically.

The reason that your final version of the functor works, though, is because the fact that the set is stored by reference means that any number of copies of tue functor will behave identically to one another.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You mean `std::remove_if` makes copy of the functor? Can you show me the code? This implementation of `std::remove_if` doesn't make copy : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/

Comment: That really depends on your implementation of the STL; I don't think that the standard says whether or not it's supposed to or must make a copy.  However, I'm pretty sure that the standard says that it **can** make a copy, and based on the output it very much seems like it is doing just that.

Comment: The answer is correct. In general your functors should not have state because they can get copied.

Comment: @Nawaz, that implementation you referenced makes at least one copy; Predicate `pred` is passed by value. However, based on your results, I suspect you are using VS2010 or related; that implementation of remove_if first calls find_if, then an internal implementation of remove_if. That makes two additional copies of `pred` which would explain your results.

Answer (score 5):

Not really an answer, but as another interesting tidbit to consider, this does work, even though it uses the original functor:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template<typename T>
struct is_repeated {
    std::set<T>  unique;
    bool operator()(T c) { return !unique.insert(c).second; }
}; 
int main() {
    std::string s= "saaangeetha";
    std::remove_copy_if(s.begin(), s.end(), 
                        std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout), 
                        is_repeated<char>());
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I don't think it affects this behavior, but I've also corrected a minor slip in your functor (operator() should apparently take a parameter of type T, not `char`).

Answer (score 4):

I suppose the problem could lie in that the `is_repeated` functor is copied somewhere inside the implementation of `std::remove_if`. If that is the case, the default copy constructor is used and this in turn calls `std::set` copy constructor. You end up with two `is_repeated` functors possibly used independently. However as the sets in both of them are distinct objects, they don't see the mutual changes. If you turn the field `is_repeated::unique` to a reference, then the copied functor still uses the original set which is what you want in this case.

Comment: I edited my question. Please read the last line where I said : if the `is_repeated` functor is copied somewhere, then every member of it is also copied. I don't see the problem here!

Comment: As I wrote, if the members are copied you have two `unique` sets. Both of them could be empty initially. Then both of them may be used to check whether character `a` is present.

Comment: @KennyTM: But copy doesn't cause the problem. I mean when the function copied, every member of it is copied, right?

Comment: a) instance no. 1 is copied into instance no. 2 b) instance no. 1 is testing `a` and adds it to its `unique` set. c) instance no. 2 does the same. As it uses another set, it still doesn't contain any `a` character and returns a result that causes the problem.

Comment: @Nawaz: No it does, since the copy is done on the empty set. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Functor classes should be pure functions and have no state of their own. See item 39 in Scott Meyer's *Effective STL* book for a good explanation on this. But the gist of it is that your functor class may be copied 1 or more times inside the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct, in that the issue is that the functor that you are using is not *copyable* safe. In particular, the STL that comes with gcc (4.2) implements `std::remove_if` as a combination of `std::find_if` to locate the first element to delete followed by a `std::remove_copy_if` to complete the operation.

```
template <typename ForwardIterator, typename Predicate>
std::remove_if( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator end, Predicate pred ) {
   first = std::find_if( first, end, pred ); // [1]
   ForwardIterator i = it;
   return first == last? first 
          : std::remove_copy_if( ++i, end, fist, pred ); // [2]
}
```

The copy in [1] means that the first element found is added to the copy of the functor and that means that the first 'a' will be lost in oblivion. The functor is also copied in [2], and that would be fine if it were not because the original for that copy is an empty functor.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the implementation of `remove_if` can make copies of your predicate. Either refactor your functor and make it stateless or use [Boost.Ref](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/ref.html) to "for passing references to function templates (algorithms) that would usually take copies of their arguments", like so:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

#include <boost/ref.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

template<typename T>
struct is_repeated {
    std::set<T>  unique;
    bool operator()(T c) { return !unique.insert(c).second; }
}; 

int main() {
    std::string s= "saaangeetha";
    s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), boost::bind<bool>(boost::ref(is_repeated<char>()),_1)), s.end());
    std::cout << s;

    return 0;
}
```