# Do STL predicates need to be pure predicates?

Tags: c++, stl, predicate

By "pure" predicates I mean they *only* depend on their arguments. So is the following function object a valid predicate for use in say, std::sort

```
// A predicate for sorting objects of type T2 that relies on an 
// object of type T1.
class APredicate {
    T1 &someObj;
    APredicate(T1 &someObject) : someObj(someObject) {};

    bool operator() (T2 thing1, T2 thing2) {
        return someObj.someFn(thing1) < someobj.someFn(thing2);
    }
}
```

Is this ever valid? Always valid? Or does it depend on what someObj.SomeFn() actually does?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is wrong with `std::set`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397616/what-is-wrong-with-stdset)

Comment: Yes. See accepted answer in possible duplicate : [What is wrong with `std::set`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397616/what-is-wrong-with-stdset)

Comment: Yes. You can read that in the link I've provided in my previous comment.

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate. Yes, the information might be gathered from that other (much more lengthy) question, but it's certainly not a duplicate.

Comment: @Nawaz: Sorry, I deleted the comment you just replied to after reading that link but before your reply appeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "only depends on their arguments" actually means "if called again with the same arguments, must return the same result as previously". If your (particular instance of) `someObj` does not change it's mind on what to return from `someObj::someFn` for particular instances of `T2` it *is* "pure".

As long as the condition holds for lifetime of the particular instance of the predicate (STL takes predicates by *value*, so each collection or operation have their own instance), it is correct (obviously it has to satisfy any other requirement of the particular collection or algorithm).

Comment: Is that implementation dependent? Or is STL guaranteed to take predicates by value?

Comment: @Nigel: It's guaranteed.  Take a look at the prototypes declared at e.g. http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/transform.html.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's fine.

Just make sure that the entire operation provides whatever stability requirements the sort needs.